# Function not calling

Tags: c#

Hi I have the following code in which I am calling a function named **ControlAdd** but the compiler debug the code till this function but **not** this function. Here is the code:

```
    void SettingControls()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            string[] ListText;
            ListText = listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split('.');
            if (ListText[0] == ";Control")
            {
                if (ListText[1] == "Form")
                {
                    this.Text = OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 2].ToString().Trim());
                    this.Width = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 3].ToString()));
                    this.Height = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 4].ToString()));
                    this.Left = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 5].ToString()));
                    this.Top = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 6].ToString()));
                }
                else
                {
                    string Control_Text;
                    string Control_Name;
                    int Control_Width, Control_Height, Control_Left, Control_Top;
                    Control_Name = OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 2].ToString().Trim());
                    Control_Text = OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 3].ToString().Trim());
                    Control_Width = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 4].ToString()));
                    Control_Height = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 5].ToString()));
                    Control_Left = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 6].ToString()));
                    Control_Top = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 7].ToString()));
                    ControlAdd(ListText[1].ToString(), Control_Name, Control_Text, Control_Width, Control_Height, Control_Left, Control_Top);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The function which is not calling by the compiler is:

```
ControlAdd(ListText[1].ToString(), Control_Name, Control_Text, Control_Width, Control_Height, Control_Left, Control_Top);
```

the compiler debug the code till this line:

```
Control_Top = Convert.ToInt16(OrganizeData(listBox1.Items[i + 7].ToString()));
```

It just skips the line. I used break point but but the program doesent stops. the compiler skips the line but no exception occure.
This program was working fine until I add a new parameter ControlName to the function control add. After adding the parameter this problem occures. I also try removing the parameter which I add but the problem still occures.

Comment: And what happens after that? You say it's not being called - what *is* happening? My guess is that the previous line is throwing an exception, but it's hard to know...

Comment: What do you mean when you say it "debug the code till this line"? Does execution stop there and produce an exception? Does the program just skip that line? If you set a breakpoint on that line, the program never breaks?

Comment: Project + Properties, Build tab, change the Platform target to x86.  This avoids a bug on a 64-bit operating system where exceptions are swallowed without diagnostic in any code that is called by a form's Load event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using try/catch error handling. thats why your debuger does not show any exception because might be your catch block is empty.

Answer (score 3):

You are looping:

```
for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
```

yet you are accessing this element of the array:

```
listBox1.Items[i + 7]
```

there is a very good chance that this is beyond the end of the array and thus causing an exception to be raised.

You need to change the end condition for your loop so that `i+7` is a valid array index.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the output folder for your project witch debugger is looking for assemblies is different from debugging assembly.

when the executing assembly (in debug mode) is different from the latest output assembly this problem occurs. you can try putting breakpoints in your code and see if the breakpoints are valid and accessible in debug mode.

Comment: If you run the project from within Visual Studio (i.e., with the debugger attached), it will *rebuild* any projects that have changed since they were last built. I can't really see this ever being a problem.

Comment: I had this problem in many situations. specially when I change the output folder.

Comment: If you change the output folder, the debugger looks for assemblies there, too.

Comment: He may loading assemblies dynamically or even debugging using attach to process! or event debugging a win service

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem stems from the fact that you're reusing items in `listBox1`. The first time you loop, you're looking at `listBox1.Items[0]` through `listBox1.Items[6]` or `listBox1.Items[7]`, but in the second loop you're looking at `listBox1.Items[1]` through `listBox1.Items[7]` or `listBox1.Items[8]`. I imagine you want something more like this:

```
void SettingControls()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        string[] ListText;
        ListText = listBox1.Items[i].ToString().Split('.');
        if (ListText[0] == ";Control")
        {
            if (ListText[1] == "Form")
            {
                ...
                i+=6;
            }
            else
            {
                ...
                i+=7;
            }
        }
    }
}
```